# How to correctly retrieve content length of a HttpListenerResponse from UnityWebRequest?

Tags: c#, http, unity-game-engine, http-headers

I have a HTTP server which returns a random byte array upon request:

```
public static Main(string[] args)
{
    HttpListener httpListener = new HttpListener();
    httpListener.Prefixes.Add(@"http://localhost:8080/");
    httpListener.Start();
    httpListener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(GetContext), httpListener);
}

private void GetContext(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    HttpListener httpListener = ar.AsyncState as HttpListener;
    HttpListenerContext context = httpListener.EndGetContext(ar);
            
    httpListener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(GetContext), httpListener);
            
    HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
    HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
            
    response.ContentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet;
    response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.ASCII;
    using (Stream output = response.OutputStream)
    {
        byte[] buffer = RandomByteArray();  //A method returns a random byte array of random size.
        response.ContentLength64= buffer.Length;
        //Or response.AddHeader("Content-Length", buffer.Length.ToString());
        output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        output.Flush();
    }
}
```

And a client using `UnityWebRequest` to retrieve the data:

```
UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(@"http://localhost:8080/","");
www.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
www.SendWebRequest();
```

I tried to retrieve the content length via `www.GetResponseHeader("Content-Length");`, but it only successfully retrieve the length "every once a very while"!

I also tried to access `downloadProgress` but it's all 0.

I had read some articles saying that these stuffs will only work when the server sets the "Content-Length" header and the client attaches `downloadHandler`, but I'm pretty sure that I fulfilled both conditions, so why am I still getting nulls and zeros?

I don't really know what had I missed.

Somebody please be so kind and help me out.

Much appreciated!

Comment: You do `yield return www.SendWebRequest();` right? It is a nonblocking call that returns an yieldable async download process .. sounds a bit like you don't wait for it to finish ...

Comment: Also note that for `UnityWebRequest.Post` the `DownloadHandlerBuffer` is the default anyway .. and does it need to be `Post` if you don't send any data anyway?

Comment: @derHugo OK, I'll tty it out, thanks!

Comment: @derHugo I tried `yield return www.SendWebRequest()`, and I wrapped `downloadProgress` inside `while(!www.isDone)` loop, I also tried to change `Post` to `Get`, but it still getting nulls and zeros.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out what my problem is:

When I tried to make the returning byte array stupidly large (over 10 million), it start to show the progress, but it's over in 5 to 10 iterations.

[image]

And the largest byte array I was trying to get earlier is not even 2 million, so basically it was finished before the system could even catch it.

[image]

What my client is "waiting" is actually "the time the server generates the byte array", not "the time the client receives the data", hence all the nulls and zeros (because the server is not even sending the data yet).

I figured it's probably because I'm using "localhost" to transmit data between the server and client, thus achieving such incredible speed, I believe if the data was to be sent through request internet, the progress should show up just fine.